# Extra Setup Required For Running Python Script in Atom Using Script Plugin?

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor

I am trying to run a Python script using Atom's Script plugin. For some reason when I hit the documented keyboard shortcut (Ctrl + Shift + B), nothing happens. I have my installation of Anaconda in my system Path variable and the atom language-Python plug-in is installed as well. What am I missing?

Any and all help is much appreciated!

**Edit:** It seems that there are two shortcuts linked to the ctrl+shift+b keyboard shortcut: "native!" and "fuzzy:finder:toggle-git-status-finder"

Comment: What happens when you open the "Key Binding Resolver" (either from the command palette, or using "Cmd+." on the Mac). What does it show when you press "Ctrl+Shift+B"?

Comment: It seems that there are two shortcuts linked: "native!" and "fuzzy:finder:toggle-git-status-finder"